ocmock is required using two different revision-based requirements
I updated my flutter version to latest and when run flutter build ios command getting this error below :->
Unable to get Xcode project information:
 2024-10-04 17:21:46.356 xcodebuild[31047:2236830] Writing error result bundle to
 /var/folders/mm/83rw22ln29qgl9n2gcnzd9600000gn/T/ResultBundle_2024-04-10_17-21-0046.xcresult
xcodebuild: error: Could not resolve package dependencies:
  ocmock is required using two different revision-based requirements (fe1661a3efed11831a6452f4b1a0c5e6ddc08c3d and
  ef21a2ece3ee092f8ed175417718bdd9b8eb7c9a), which is not supported

flutter version detail :->
Flutter 3.24.3 • channel stable • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision 2663184aa7 (3 weeks ago) • 2024-09-11 16:27:48 -0500
Engine • revision 36335019a8
Tools • Dart 3.5.3 • DevTools 2.37.3


I tried to remove ocmock from podfile using post_install that code is also below:->
post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    if target.name == 'OCMock'
      target.remove_from_project
    end
  end
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    if target.name == 'ocmock'
      target.remove_from_project
    end
  end

So please provide the solution to resolve this.
